# Invalid use of :: - C++ forbids use of vector without type

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have stumbled on a compile error that makes no sense to me.  So, of course, I turn to StackOverflow.....

**System**

Linux (Ubuntu 10.04 32 bit, gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3, Eclipse Indigo

** Question **

Obvious question, of course;  What is gcc complaining about?

**Background**

I have a class, ThreadTime, coded in its own cpp and h files, ThreadTime.cpp and .h and inside its own namespace THREAD_TIME;

In main() I launch two threads, call then ThreadA and ThreadB, then go into an infinite loop that sleeps 2 seconds then checks to see if ThreadA and ThreadB are still running.  in particular, if ThreadA has stopped, it gets restarted.

Each thread creates an associated ThreadTime object.  In both of my threads there are loops.  During each loop, the ThreadTimer get updated (in < 2 secs) so the main() loop can see that time is advancing in the threads.

As each ThreadTimer is created its address is added to a global vector, g_CthreadVector, of type `std::vector<ThreadTime*>`.  g_CthreadVector is file global in ThreadType.cpp.

It's probably best to just paste the whole class here.  So...

**ThreadTime.cpp**

```
#include "ThreadTime.

namespace THREAD_TIME
{
   std::vector<ThreadTime*>      g_CthreadVector; // threads to kill and monitor

   ThreadTime::ThreadTime(thread_t* a, time_t b, void* c)
     : m_pthread(a), m_time(b), m_lasttime(b-2), m_function(c), m_terminate (FALSE)
   {
      m_name = "a ThreadTime object";
      g_CthreadVector.push_back( this );
   }

   ThreadTime::~ThreadTime()
   {
      std::vector<ThreadTime*>::iterator     it       (GetIterator());
      if ( it != g_CthreadVector.end() )
         g_CthreadVector.erase( it );
   }

   void     ThreadTime::UpdateTime( void )
   {
      m_lasttime = m_time;                                              // save the time to lasttime
      m_time = time(NULL);                                              // store the current time
      if ( m_lasttime == m_time )                                       // safety valve keep m_time
         m_lasttime--;                                                  //     ahead of m_lasttime
   }

   //---------------------------------------------------------
   // did time get advanced?
   //---------------------------------------------------------
   bool     ThreadTime::TimeAdvanced( void )
   {
      if ( m_lasttime < m_time )       return TRUE;
      else                             return FALSE;
   }

   void     ThreadTime::print( void )
   {
      std::vector<ThreadTime*>::iterator      tt_it   (GetIterator());
      std::vector<ThreadTime*>::iterator      it      (g_CthreadVector.end());

         for ( it = g_CthreadVector.begin(); it < g_CthreadVector.end(); it++ )
         {
            if ( tt_it == it )
               std::cout << "  ################### CURRENT OBJECT ###################### " << std::endl;
            else
               std::cout << "  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ " << std::endl;

            std::cout << "  ThreadTime Object: " << (*it)->getName()    << std::endl
                      << "         thread ptr: " << (*it)->m_pthread    << std::endl
                      << "               time: " << (*it)->m_time       << std::endl
                      << "           lasttime: " << (*it)->m_lasttime   << std::endl
                      << "       function ptr: " << (*it)->m_function   << std::endl
                      << "          terminate: " << (*it)->m_terminate  << std::endl;
         }
         std::cout << "  $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ " << std::endl;
   }     // for ( it ... )

   std::vector<ThreadTime*>::iterator  ThreadTime::GetIterator( void )
   {
      std::vector<ThreadTime*>::iterator      it      (g_CthreadVector.end());

      for ( it = g_CthreadVector.begin(); it < g_CthreadVector.end(); it++)
      {
         if ( (*it)->m_pthread == m_pthread )
            break;
      }

      return it;
   }

} /* namespace THREAD_TIME */
```

**ThreadTime.h**

```
#ifndef THREADTIME_H_
   #define THREADTIME_H_

   #include "platform.h"
   #include "opsys_common.h"
   #include "NAS_Thread.h"


   namespace THREAD_TIME
   {
      class ThreadTime;

      class ThreadTime
      {
         public:
            std::string       getName() const                  { return m_name; }
            void              setName(std::string name)        { m_name = name; }

            ThreadTime(thread_t* a, time_t b, void* c);
            ~ThreadTime();
            void     UpdateTime( void );
            bool     TimeAdvanced( void );
            void     print( void );

         private:
            std::vector<ThreadTime*>::iterator       GetIterator( void );

            std::string    m_name;
            thread_t*      m_pthread;
            time_t         m_time;
            time_t         m_lasttime;
            void*          m_function;
            bool           m_terminate;
   };

} /* namespace THREAD_TIME */

#endif /* THREADTIME_H_ */
```

And finally, here are the error messages:

> expected `‘;’` before `‘<’` token    ThreadTime.h    line 37
>
> invalid use of `‘::’`                ThreadTime.h   Line 37
>
> ISO C++ forbids declaration of `‘vector’` with no type     ThreadTime.h   line 37

Comment: Is there a dot instead of a closing quote in your first `#include` directive?

Comment: I'm guessing you are not including <vector> in ThreadTime.h

Comment: You don't need to post the entire class, you just need to post a [minimal test case](http://sscce.org/)–complete, concise and representative. The code to output to the console (for example) is extraneous. Also, please always mark which line(s) produce/s the error(s).

Comment: Kudos also to @Anon Mail who left a comment that I can't up vote.  Yes, I forgot the #include <vector>.  And, no, there isn't aperiod instead of a closing quote.  There's a tired typist who fat-fingered something.  <grin>  Thanks to all.  Update made to original posting.

Comment: Whenever you see an error along the lines of "expected ';' before 'something'" it almmost always means you've tried to use a type that the compiler doesn't know.  Usually this is because either you haven't included the proper headers, haven't qualified it's namesspace, or left out some template parameters.  It could also mean that you've missed a semicolon in a prior declaration -- like, for example, a `class` declaration.

Comment: @Wes Miller, **Please** do not edit the post to "move to resolved state" as you have done here.  Leave the original problematic code, question and title in place.  The presence of an accepted answer is more than enough to indicate that this issue has been resolved.  Please roll back your most recent edit.

Comment: #include "ThreadTime". does this file exist? It's missing the .h

Comment: @John Dibling StackOverflow seems to have two massively conflicting gangs of etiquette police.  Half the time i see articles with corrected original posts and half not.  Seem no matter which I do there is always a complainer.  Ditto the bit about posting the whole class.  Half the posts I see ask the OP to "post more, post more" and bersides, noone  would have noticed my missing #include if I hadn't included the edge bits of the class.  I will follow your suggestion.

Comment: @WesMiller:  Yes, there are a lot of different opinions about how things are supposed to be on SO.  You can't please everyone.  I base my advice off of what I read in Meta, for the most part.

Comment: @John Dibling  Meta - Probably a place to visit one of these days.  thanks for the advice.  Seems some moderator/editor fixed it for me anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no declaration of `std::vector` in scope for your class. You need a `#include <vector>`.